# Can I use JAX-RS 2.0 in Java EE 6 application

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-6

As we know **JAX-RS 1.1** is part of **Java EE 6**.

Is it possible to use **JAX-RS 2.0** as a dependency in **Java EE 6** application?

Comment: By "application", do you mean "container"? if not, can you explain what you mean by "application".

Comment: @peeskillet a web application based on Java EE 6 profiles. The container could be Glassfish, Weblogic, or anything, which at least supports Java EE 6 profiles.

Comment: The problem is that JAX-RS can be used along side other EE components like CDI and EJB for injection. If you are using JAX-RS alone, it is possible to use a newer version, but don't expect any of integrations I mentioned to work. JAX-RS simply runs as a servlet, so you would just need to configure the servlet. Wether or not it would cause problems with classloading, it depends on the server. You might need to disable the older version if you run into classloading issues (where the older version is still loaded)

Comment: As far a Glassfish goes, I don't know. I think I once read that some other part of the server in Glassfish 3 (which is EE 6) needs JAX-RS (maybe some admin portal, I forgot), so I don't know if you can disable it. WebLogic, I'm not sure, I've never used it. Best thing is to just google it to see if anyone has had any success, and provides some step by step guide on how to do it.

Comment: @peeskillet thank you for your input. I understand your point but I am more interested in the compatibility of version 2.0 of JAX-RS with Java EE 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec for [JSR 339: JAX-RS 2.0: The Java API for RESTful Web Services](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) explicitly addresses whether it is possible to use it in a Java EE 6 application, and the answer is yes:

> 2.2 What is the target Java platform? (i.e., desktop, server, personal, embedded, card, etc.)
>
> **This specification is targeted for Java SE 6.0 or higher and Java EE 6
>   or higher platforms**.
>
> 2.3 The Executive Committees would like to ensure JSR submitters think about how their proposed technology relates to all of the Java
>   platform editions. Please provide details here for which platform
>   editions are being targeted by this JSR, and how this JSR has
>   considered the relationship with the other platform editions.
>
> This JSR will be available standalone. It is also targeted for
>   inclusion in the Java EE 7 platform. Additionally, **Java EE 6 products
>   will be allowed to implement JAX-RS 2.0 instead of JAX-RS 1.1**.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**Update:**

A few more points of clarification:

- See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416704 which fixed an bug where Eclipse incorrectly required Java 7 rather than Java 6 when using JAX-RS 2.0 facets.
- O'Reilly's [RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028925.do) only requires "JDK 6.0 or later" to run its examples.
- Note that [JAX-RS 2.1](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr370/index.html) requires Java 8 since "The API will make extensive use of annotations and lambda expressions that require Java SE 8 or later."

Comment: 'will be allowed' is a recommendation or it mean the currently available implementations support Java EE 6?

Comment: @abbas No, it's not a "recommendation"; it's an assertion, and it would have been clearer if the spec had stated "shall be allowed" rather than "will be allowed". I understand "Java EE 6 products" to mean software (e.g. Tomcat EE) that is certified as being Java EE 6 compliant. So the spec is stating that software will not fail to obtain EE 6 certification if it used JAX-RS 2.0 rather than JAX-RS 1.x. (I've also added a some clarification to my post above.)

Comment: Seems like the O'Reilly's point is an error in the book http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920028925

Comment: Just confirming: if I include javax.ws.rs-api-2.0 as a dependency in my Java EE 6 web application, it should deploy fine on a Java EE 6 compliant container?

Comment: @abbas Nice catch on the O'Reilly errata, but the issue raised was a build problem using RestEasy. That doesn't necessarily mean the actual problem was using JAX-RS 2.0 with EE 6.

Comment: @abbas Yes, if you include javax.ws.rs-api-2.0 as a dependency in my Java EE 6 web application, it should deploy fine on a Java EE 6 compliant container. That's what the spec says.